# Why is my WPF Frame not rendering anything? Known bug?

Tags: wpf, frame

I have a WPF Frame with a web-based HTML source and though the contents are there, they aren't showing up.   I know that the content is there because if I right click in just the right spot I can save images.  Also, if I do print preview it shows just fine.  The stuff is there, but it isn't showing up.  Is there a known bug?

Comment: Can you post your code / XAML?

Comment: I've found that if I take the AllowsVisibility off of the window, it works fine.  I found that it is a bug with Frame and opacity not being compatible.  But my Frame is completely opaque.  I'm just using visibility to have a drop shadow effect.  Frankly, if Frame can't deal with Opacity it shouldn't be a WPF control.  This is soooo stupid!

Comment: Heh, if that's the biggest frustration you ever get trying to deal with WebBrowser and Frame in WPF you're doing mighty well :D

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the optimism.:)  When will Microsoft create a non-ActiveX alternative to there web browser control?  This is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used code from [here](http://davidfulop.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!BC8EF43294ECB87!427.entry?wa=wsignin1.0&sa=73709929) to create a placeholder control with a window that floats right above it, so I could put the frame in the window.  Its a hack but it works... *sigh*.